# Roquette's theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I came across the following theorem by Roquette in:
http://www.uni-kiel.de/math/algebra/laue/vorlesungen/grth/grpth13.british.pdf

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\omega$ a set of primes. Let $N\triangleleft G$ such that $A^{\omega}(N)=N$. Let $H\le G$ such that $H\cap N\in Hall_{\omega}(N)$. If $H\cap N\le \Phi(H)$, then $H\cap N=1$.

$\Phi(H)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $H$.

I would please like to know if there are some known applications of it.

Comment: Can you give a link to Roquette's paper (if the theorem is by him)?

Comment: Please see above for the link.

Comment: Thank you, these are great lecture notes! "Experts will soon discover that among the results proved in this course there are certain
theorems which frequently are viewed as too difficult to reach, like Tate’s (4.10) or Roquette’s (5.13)." So, then, who cares about further applications. It is used in the context, see the Corollary etc.. I suppose it can also be used for character theory.